# set optional/required property according to condition

Tags: python, properties, option-type, required

I have this:

```
def required(props):
    props.fget.required = True
    return props

class SomeClass():
    @required
    @property
    def func(self):
         return self.conname("conname")
```

But I want this: when self.name attribute of SomeClass equale "value" , then make the property optional, when non-equal leave required.

Comment: i tried to make Class inherited from `property` (to decorate with this class), but there was the problem with arguments number, that i didnt understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this in the initializer like so:

```
class SomeClass(object): # inherit from object if you are using python 2.7
    def __init__(self, name, optional_required_property=None):
        self.name = name
        if name == "value" and optional_required_property is None:
            raise AttributeError("optional_required_property cannot be None.")
        else:
            self.optional_required_property = optional_required_property
test_someclass = SomeClass("test") # will work
test_someclass = SomeClass("value") # will fail
```

Inspired by [Stack Overflow Question: How to implement a required property in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465686/how-to-implement-a-required-property-in-python)